Iterate over batch size for each batch
Its there a more pythonic way, or built in function in python to do the following:
def batch(number, batch_size):
    number_left = number
    while number_left:
        if number_left >= batch_size:
            yield batch_size
            number_left -= batch_size
        else:
            yield number_left
            number_left = 0

batch(21,10) outputs: [10,10,1]

@chepner Sorry, fixed that.

What are you going to do with those numbers? There might be a more pythonic way to do that without them.

You don't need repeated subtraction. Compute the quotient q and the remainder r, then yield the batch_size q times before finally yielding the remainder.
from itertools import repeat


def batch(number, batch_size):
    q, r = divmod(number, batch_size)
    yield from repeat(batch_size, q)
    if r:
        yield r

If you don't want to divide, let the condition take number and batch_size into consideration.
def batch(number, batch_size):
    while batch_size <= number:
        yield batch_size
        number -= batch_size
    if number:
        yield number


Thanks @chepner. The first solution will yield [10,10,0] for batch(20,10)

I've fixed both to avoid yielding 0 when batch_size divides number evenly.

You can use min() or max(), if you are interested in both cases...
def batch(number, batch_size):
    while number > 0:
        yield min(batch_size, number)
        number -= batch_size

res = list(batch(21, 10))
print(res) = [10, 10, 1]


If you don't want to decrement.
def batch(number, batch_size):
    batches, mod = divmod(number, batch_size)
    for _ in range(batches):
        yield batch_size
    if mod:
        yield mod

